# Xna rotate around world axis?

Tags: xna, c#

I want to make it so that either the pitch yaw or roll rotates around the world axis and not the local axis, but I'm not sure how, I've got.

```
Vector2 mouse_change = new Vector2(mouse_previous.X - mouse_new.X, mouse_previous.Y - mouse_new.Y);
camera_angles *= Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), mouse_change.X / 800f);
camera_angles *= Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(new Vector3(1, 0, 0), mouse_change.Y / 800f);
```

Updating every frame, then I've got.

```
view_matrix = Matrix.Invert(Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(camera_angles) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(camera_position));
projection_matrix = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, device.Viewport.AspectRatio, 0.2f, 500f);
```

The problem is that if I e.g. change the pitch then change the yaw then the yaw changes through the local axis, I need it to turn around the world axis so that it doesn't matter what the yaw is :/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try function [Quaterion.CreateFromYawPitchRoll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.quaternion.createfromyawpitchroll.aspx). It should create the correct quaterion.

Or if you are using this only for view matrix, you may want also try [Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix.createfromyawpitchroll.aspx).

Comment: No they both do the same thing...

Comment: I fixed it, kind of stupid that I didn't do this in the first place.  I just made a vector3 for my angles and then added the angles to that and then calculated the quaternion from that, come to think of it I think that may be what you where suggesting :/.  Thanks for the help :).